Missing borders CSS /HTML
In my table I've implemented logic to highlight the Row/Column when the cell is selected but i don't seem to manage to get the borders on top and bottom of the column correct. The border on the bottom is missing as well as on top and the Header row is excluded as well which it shouldn't
Screenshot:

Here is the full code of the iframe


        // Static test data
        const correlationData5y = {
            "Stock A": { "Stock A": 1.0, "Stock B": 0.75, "Stock C": -0.3 },
            "Stock B": { "Stock A": 0.75, "Stock B": 1.0, "Stock C": 0.2 },
            "Stock C": { "Stock A": -0.3, "Stock B": 0.2, "Stock C": 1.0 }
        };

        // Prepare the table
        const tableBody = document.querySelector('#correlationTable tbody');
        const tableHeaders = document.querySelector('#tableHeaders');
        
        // Extract tickers from the keys of the correlation data
        const tickers = Object.keys(correlationData5y);

        // Generate table headers dynamically from the tickers
        const headerRow = document.createElement('th');
        headerRow.textContent = ''; // Top-left corner (empty)
        tableHeaders.appendChild(headerRow);  // Add the empty top-left cell
        tickers.forEach(ticker => {
            const headerCell = document.createElement('th');
            headerCell.textContent = ticker; // Add ticker as header
            tableHeaders.appendChild(headerCell);
        });

        // Helper function to determine the cell color class based on correlation value
        function getCellClass(value) {
            if (value < 0) return 'negative'; // Light blue for negative correlations
            if (value < 0.3) return 'low';     // Medium light blue for low correlations
            if (value < 0.6) return 'medium';  // Medium dark blue for medium correlations
            return 'high';                    // Dark blue for high correlations
        }

        // Create rows for the table dynamically from the data
        tickers.forEach(tickerRow => {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            const headerCell = document.createElement('th');
            headerCell.textContent = tickerRow;  // Row header (ticker)
            row.appendChild(headerCell);

            tickers.forEach(tickerCol => {
                const cell = document.createElement('td');
                const value = correlationData5y[tickerRow][tickerCol];
                cell.textContent = value.toFixed(2);  // Show correlation value with 2 decimals
                cell.classList.add('heatmap-cell', getCellClass(value));  // Add the appropriate color class
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });

            tableBody.appendChild(row);
        });

        // Highlight row and column, changing styles only as needed
        const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
        tableCells.forEach(cell => {
            cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
                const rowIdx = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
                const colIdx = cell.cellIndex;

                // Highlight the row
                const row = tableBody.rows[rowIdx - 1]; // Adjust for header row
                row.classList.add('highlight-row');

                // Highlight the column
                tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
                    const targetCell = row.cells[colIdx];
                    if (targetCell) targetCell.classList.add('highlight-column');
                });

                // Highlight the specific cell
                cell.classList.add('highlight-cell');
            });

            cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
                const rowIdx = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
                const colIdx = cell.cellIndex;

                // Remove row highlight
                const row = tableBody.rows[rowIdx - 1];
                row.classList.remove('highlight-row');

                // Remove column highlight
                tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row => {
                    const targetCell = row.cells[colIdx];
                    if (targetCell) targetCell.classList.remove('highlight-column');
                });

                // Remove cell highlight
                cell.classList.remove('highlight-cell');
            });
        });
        /* General Page Styling */
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: #141416;  /* Dark background */
            color: #fff;  /* White text for contrast */
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;  /* Smaller title font */
            margin-bottom: 20px;  /* Reduced space */
            color: #FD6262;  /* Red color for titles */
        }

        table {
            width: 70%;  /* Reduced table width */
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #222;  /* Dark table background */
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 8px;  /* Reduced padding */
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;  /* Smaller font size */
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            border: 1px solid #444;  /* Dark border for all sides */
        }

        th {
            background-color: #141416;  
            color: #FD6262;  /* Red color for text */
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 12px;  /* Smaller font size for data */
            color: #fff;  /* White text color for values */
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        /* Gradient color scale for the heatmap (from light blue to dark blue) */
        .negative {
            background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.2);  /* Light blue for negative correlations */
        }

        .low {
            background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.4);  /* Medium light blue for low correlations */
        }

        .medium {
            background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.6);  /* Medium dark blue for medium correlations */
        }

        .high {
            background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 1);  /* Dark blue for high correlations */
        }

        /* Hover effect */
        td:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* Container for scroll */
        .table-container {
            overflow-x: auto;
            margin-top: 30px;  /* Adjusted margin */
        }

        /* Highlighted row style */
        .highlight-row {
            border: 2px solid #FD6262;  /* Red border for the row */
            
        }

        /* Highlighted column style */
        .highlight-column {
            border-left: 2px solid #FD6262; /* Red border on the left */
            border-right: 2px solid #FD6262; /* Red border on the right */
          
        }

        /* Highlighted cell style */
        .highlight-cell {
            border: 2px solid #FD6262;  /* Dark red border for the selected cell */
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);  /* Light red background for the selected cell */
           /* z-index: 1;  Bring cell to the top if needed */
        }
    <div class="table-container">
        <table id="correlationTable">
            <thead>
                <tr id="tableHeaders">
                    <!-- Table headers will be populated dynamically -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Table rows will be populated by JavaScript -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



Tried to have a consistent Highlighting but there is Boarders missing as you can see in the Image and described above

The hover effect is missing the border at the bottom of the "selected" column, as well as at the top, and the header row doesn't have any borders at all. I want the hover effect to create a border around the entire row and column, including the ticker symbols.
The Boarders around the Row are perfect its just the Column that looks different

"The hover effect is missing the border at the bottom of the "selected" column, as well as at the top" - you are currently applying borders on all sides of the hovered cell only; for all other cells in that same column, you are applying a border on the left and right side only. .highlight-column should also apply the border on all sides. "and the header row doesn't have any borders at all" - you're currently looping over the td elements only, that leaves the th elements untouched.

I would prefer it if the border size, when hovering, was the same as the normal border size. Now the table cells move around slightly when hovering.

It is not normal table structure. Hence, a bit tricky to achieve your desired output.
If the table was of normal structure then it would have been easier.
Anyway, I have updated the css code to match your requirement.
Removed your few css from trs and tds and have added few css to target last rows of the tables and last cells of table columns.
The hardest part was to achieve to the top border of the table which was added by addition of new css rule (tr#tableHeaders).
Feel free to ask which part you do not get.


// Static test data
const correlationData5y = {
  "Stock A": { "Stock A": 1.0, "Stock B": 0.75, "Stock C": -0.3 },
  "Stock B": { "Stock A": 0.75, "Stock B": 1.0, "Stock C": 0.2 },
  "Stock C": { "Stock A": -0.3, "Stock B": 0.2, "Stock C": 1.0 },
}

// Prepare the table
const tableBody = document.querySelector("#correlationTable tbody")
const tableHeaders = document.querySelector("#tableHeaders")

// Extract tickers from the keys of the correlation data
const tickers = Object.keys(correlationData5y)

// Generate table headers dynamically from the tickers
const headerRow = document.createElement("th")
headerRow.textContent = "" // Top-left corner (empty)
tableHeaders.appendChild(headerRow) // Add the empty top-left cell
tickers.forEach((ticker) => {
  const headerCell = document.createElement("th")
  headerCell.textContent = ticker // Add ticker as header
  tableHeaders.appendChild(headerCell)
})

// Helper function to determine the cell color class based on correlation value
function getCellClass(value) {
  if (value < 0) return "negative" // Light blue for negative correlations
  if (value < 0.3) return "low" // Medium light blue for low correlations
  if (value < 0.6) return "medium" // Medium dark blue for medium correlations
  return "high" // Dark blue for high correlations
}

// Create rows for the table dynamically from the data
tickers.forEach((tickerRow) => {
  const row = document.createElement("tr")
  const headerCell = document.createElement("th")
  headerCell.textContent = tickerRow // Row header (ticker)
  row.appendChild(headerCell)

  tickers.forEach((tickerCol) => {
    const cell = document.createElement("td")
    const value = correlationData5y[tickerRow][tickerCol]
    cell.textContent = value.toFixed(2) // Show correlation value with 2 decimals
    cell.classList.add("heatmap-cell", getCellClass(value)) // Add the appropriate color class
    row.appendChild(cell)
  })

  tableBody.appendChild(row)
})

// Highlight row and column, changing styles only as needed
const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll("td")
tableCells.forEach((cell) => {
  cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    const rowIdx = cell.parentNode.rowIndex
    const colIdx = cell.cellIndex

    // Highlight the row
    const row = tableBody.rows[rowIdx - 1] // Adjust for header row
    row.classList.add("highlight-row")

    // Highlight the column
    tableBody.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((row) => {
      const targetCell = row.cells[colIdx]
      if (targetCell) targetCell.classList.add("highlight-column")
    })

    // Highlight the specific cell
    cell.classList.add("highlight-cell")
  })

  cell.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    const rowIdx = cell.parentNode.rowIndex
    const colIdx = cell.cellIndex

    // Remove row highlight
    const row = tableBody.rows[rowIdx - 1]
    row.classList.remove("highlight-row")

    // Remove column highlight
    tableBody.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((row) => {
      const targetCell = row.cells[colIdx]
      if (targetCell) targetCell.classList.remove("highlight-column")
    })

    // Remove cell highlight
    cell.classList.remove("highlight-cell")
  })
})
/* General Page Styling */
body {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #141416; /* Dark background */
  color: #fff; /* White text for contrast */
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px; /* Smaller title font */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* Reduced space */
  color: #fd6262; /* Red color for titles */
}

table {
  width: 70%; /* Reduced table width */
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #222; /* Dark table background */
}

tr {
  border-top: 2px solid #444; /* Dark border for all sides */
  border-left: 2px solid #444;
}

tr#tableHeaders {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px; /* Reduced padding */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px; /* Smaller font size */
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #444;
}
td:last-child:hover {
  border-right: 2px solid #fd6262;
}
tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
  border-top: 2px solid #444;
}

th {
  background-color: #141416;
  color: #fd6262; /* Red color for text */
  font-weight: bold;
}

td {
  color: #fff; /* White text color for values */
}

/* Gradient color scale for the heatmap (from light blue to dark blue) */
.negative {
  background-color: rgba(
    52,
    152,
    219,
    0.2
  ); /* Light blue for negative correlations */
}

.low {
  background-color: rgba(
    52,
    152,
    219,
    0.4
  ); /* Medium light blue for low correlations */
}

.medium {
  background-color: rgba(
    52,
    152,
    219,
    0.6
  ); /* Medium dark blue for medium correlations */
}

.high {
  background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 1); /* Dark blue for high correlations */
}

/* Hover effect */
th:hover,
td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Container for scroll */
.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin-top: 30px; /* Adjusted margin */
}

/* Highlighted row style */


tr.highlight-row {
  border-top: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border for the row */
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border for the row */
}

tr.highlight-row:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border for the row */
}

/* Highlighted column style */
.highlight-column {
  border-left: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border on the left */
  border-right: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border on the right */
}

.highlight-column:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border on the right */
}

/* Highlighted cell style */
.highlight-cell {
  border: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Dark red border for the selected cell */
  background-color: rgba(
    255,
    0,
    0,
    0.2
  ); /* Light red background for the selected cell */
  /* z-index: 1;  Bring cell to the top if needed */
}
<div class="table-container">
  <table id="correlationTable">
    <thead>
      <tr id="tableHeaders">
        <!-- Table headers will be populated dynamically -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- Table rows will be populated by JavaScript -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



Hope, this helps.

The following code should work.
    tr:is(:not(:first-of-type), :not(:last-of-type)) .highlight-column{
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}

tr:first-of-type .highlight-column{
    border-top: 2px solid #FD6262;
}

tr:last-of-type .highlight-column{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FD6262;
}

I have used the type selectors to select the "highlight-column" class based on the order which it gets appended. i.e. selecting the "highlight-column" class which comes under the first and last occurrence of the tr. Hope this helps.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
  /* General Page Styling */
  body {
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #141416; /* Dark background */
    color: #fff; /* White text for contrast */
  }

  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px; /* Smaller title font */
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* Reduced space */
    color: #fd6262; /* Red color for titles */
  }

  table {
    width: 70%; /* Reduced table width */
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #222; /* Dark table background */
  }

  th,
  td {
    padding: 8px; /* Reduced padding */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px; /* Smaller font size */
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    border: 1px solid #444; /* Dark border for all sides */
  }

  th {
    background-color: #141416;
    color: #fd6262; /* Red color for text */
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  td {
    font-size: 12px; /* Smaller font size for data */
    color: #fff; /* White text color for values */
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  /* Gradient color scale for the heatmap (from light blue to dark blue) 
  */
  .negative {
    background-color: rgba(
      52,
      152,
      219,
      0.2
    ); /* Light blue for negative correlations */
  }

  .low {
    background-color: rgba(
      52,
      152,
      219,
      0.4
    ); /* Medium light blue for low correlations */
  }

  .medium {
    background-color: rgba(
      52,
      152,
      219,
      0.6
    ); /* Medium dark blue for medium correlations */
  }

  .high {
    background-color: rgba(
      52,
      152,
      219,
      1
    ); /* Dark blue for high correlations */
  }

  /* Hover effect */
  td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Container for scroll */
  .table-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-top: 30px; /* Adjusted margin */
  }

  /* Highlighted row style */
  .highlight-row {
    border: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border for the row */
  }

  /* Highlighted column style */
  .highlight-column {
    border-left: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Red border on the left */
    border-right: 2px solid #fd6262;
    border-top: 2px solid #fd6262;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fd6262; 

  /* Highlighted cell style */
  .highlight-cell {
    border: 2px solid #fd6262; /* Dark red border for the selected cell */
    background-color: rgba(
      255,
      0,
      0,
      0.2
    ); /* Light red background for the selected cell */
    /* z-index: 1;  Bring cell to the top if needed */
  }
    </style>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div class="table-container">
      <table id="correlationTable">
      <thead>
       <tr id="tableHeaders">
        <!-- Table headers will be populated dynamically -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- Table rows will be populated by JavaScript -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>

 <script>
  // Static test data
  const correlationData5y = {
    "Stock A": { "Stock A": 1.0, "Stock B": 0.75, "Stock C": -0.3 },
    "Stock B": { "Stock A": 0.75, "Stock B": 1.0, "Stock C": 0.2 },
    "Stock C": { "Stock A": -0.3, "Stock B": 0.2, "Stock C": 1.0 },
  };

  // Prepare the table
  const tableBody = document.querySelector("#correlationTable tbody");
  const tableHeaders = document.querySelector("#tableHeaders");

  // Extract tickers from the keys of the correlation data
  const tickers = Object.keys(correlationData5y);

  // Generate table headers dynamically from the tickers
  const headerRow = document.createElement("th");
  headerRow.textContent = ""; // Top-left corner (empty)
  tableHeaders.appendChild(headerRow); // Add the empty top-left cell
  tickers.forEach((ticker) => {
    const headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.textContent = ticker; // Add ticker as header
    tableHeaders.appendChild(headerCell);
  });

  // Helper function to determine the cell color class based on 
      correlation value
  function getCellClass(value) {
    if (value < 0) return "negative"; // Light blue for negative 
       correlations
    if (value < 0.3) return "low"; // Medium light blue for low 
      correlations
    if (value < 0.6) return "medium"; // Medium dark blue for medium 
     correlations
    return "high"; // Dark blue for high correlations
    }

  // Create rows for the table dynamically from the data
  tickers.forEach((tickerRow) => {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    const headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.textContent = tickerRow; // Row header (ticker)
    row.appendChild(headerCell);

    tickers.forEach((tickerCol) => {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      const value = correlationData5y[tickerRow][tickerCol];
      cell.textContent = value.toFixed(2); // Show correlation value with 
   2 decimals
         cell.classList.add("heatmap-cell", getCellClass(value)); // Add 
  the appropriate color class
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  // Highlight row and column, changing styles only as needed
  const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll("td");
  tableCells.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      const rowIdx = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
      const colIdx = cell.cellIndex;

      // Highlight the row
      const row = tableBody.rows[rowIdx - 1]; // Adjust for header row
      row.classList.add("highlight-row");

      // Highlight the column
      tableBody.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((row) => {
        const targetCell = row.cells[colIdx];
        if (targetCell) targetCell.classList.add("highlight-column");
      });

      // Highlight the specific cell
      cell.classList.add("highlight-cell");
    });

    cell.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      const rowIdx = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
      const colIdx = cell.cellIndex;

      // Remove row highlight
      const row = tableBody.rows[rowIdx - 1];
      row.classList.remove("highlight-row");

      // Remove column highlight
      tableBody.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach((row) => {
        const targetCell = row.cells[colIdx];
        if (targetCell) targetCell.classList.remove("highlight-column");
      });

      // Remove cell highlight
      cell.classList.remove("highlight-cell");
      });
    });
 </script>
</body>


Dear @Vijay-Kovvali. I see this is one of your first answers on Stack Overflow and I thought maybe you need some help. I suggest to read some materials about how to answer questions so you will be able to support other with your knowledge in the best way. For instnace your answer is missing a runnig example, its not very clear how your solution should be implemented. All best! –
